# How to generate random long hexadecimal in Swift?

Tags: swift, hex

I am trying to generate a random 6 bytes long hex but I ma having problems. the error I am getting is: "Integer literal overflows when stored into 'UInt32'".

Here is my code:

```
var baseInt = UInt64(arc4random() % 281474976710655)
var str = String(format: "%06X", baseInt)
println("\(str)")
```

Any help?

Comment: `arc4random` is 32-bit. Make three 16-bit numbers and paste them together?

Comment: Thanks @Amadan but the code works with lower integers, I tested it, but not with that long one which I need. So I must use that code, just need to get rid of that error which I don't know how.

Comment: Again, [`arc4random`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) generates 32-bit numbers. You can "make it work" by first upgrading `arc4random()` result into `UInt64` and *then* getting a modulo, but you will always get numbers like `00XXXX`, simply because there are not enough bits in the result of `arc4random` to give you what you want. It's like asking "how do I survive with 200 calories a day? I can do it for an hour, so I just need to make it work with the longer period but I don't know how."

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Swift does not use suffixes for integer literals; literals are (in theory) infinite in precision, and they adapt to circumstances, and in this case it is `UInt32` because `arc4random()` is `UInt32`. So `UInt64(arc4random()) % 281474976710655` works (but is useless for reasons described above).

Comment: @Amadan I used your tip and it now works.

Answer (score 4):

Following @Amadan suggestion I got it working.

```
var baseIntA = Int(arc4random() % 65535)
var baseIntB = Int(arc4random() % 65535)
var str = String(format: "%06X%06X", baseIntA, baseIntB)
println("\(str)")
```

Then it outputs: "009DD7004974

Comment: You should avoid using arc4random()

Comment: And what you would suggest?

Comment: let baseIntA = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt16.max)))

Comment: Ok, but could you tell me the difference?

Comment: https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/generating-random-numbers-without-modulo-bias/

Comment: String(format: "%06X%06X", arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt16.max)), arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt16.max)))